# session management c#.net and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, database, session

I am creating a website(shopping cart) in C#.net and mysql. In .net and sql server we can manage session in sql server. Is this possible same way using mysql and if yes then how? another question - storing a session in database is correct approach for shopping cart or should i store in memory ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 questions here really ;) - you can store your cart wherever you like, but you must *think* about the transient nature of data and how much persistence you would like. In-memory carts will only last for the duration of a Session, out of state would last til the server rebooted, sql would last...well, forever (ish) - to me the only real option is to use both In memory and DB! cache the cart til it changes, then bung it in the DB when it does.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 3 "built-in" [session storage methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) in the .NET Framework:

- **InProc** mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server.
  This is the default.
- **StateServer** mode, which stores session state in a separate process
  called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is
  preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session
  state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
- **SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This
  ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is
  restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web
  servers in a Web farm.

As you can see, the only one that supports serialisation to a database is SQL Server. However, there is a fourth option - create your own [custom session storage provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx). You can implement a custom session-state store provider by creating a class that inherits the `SessionStateStoreProviderBase` class. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) on MSDN describes how.

However, you may want to just use StateServer mode as this mitigates many of the risks of using InProc (which are that Session state can easily be lost if memory becomes low, an app pool is recycled or the application restarted). Just remember to mark all your classes with the `[Serializable()]` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx). I'd only use database if you want to retain shopping cart information after the user leaves the site.